# FileOutputStream set encoding to utf-8

Tags: java, utf-8

a want to set a file to utf-8

the FileOutputStream takes just two parameter

my code is

```
 PrintWriter kitaba1 = null;

    try {
       kitaba1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(ismmilaf), true ));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //kitaba1.println(moarif1);
    kitaba1.close();
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `OutputStreamWriter` so you can specify an output charset.  You can then wrap that in a `PrintWriter` or `BufferedWriter` if you need printing semantics:

```
PrintWriter kitaba1 = null;

try {
   kitaba1 = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(ismmilaf), true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

//kitaba1.println(moarif1);
kitaba1.close();
```

```
BufferedWriter kitaba1 = null;

try {
   kitaba1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(ismmilaf), true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

//kitaba1.write(moarif1);
//kitaba1.newLine()
kitaba1.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

FileOutputStream is meant to be used to write binary data. If you want to write text you can use a FileWriter or an OutputStreamWriter.

Alternatively you could use one of the methods in [the `Files` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), for example:

```
Path p = Paths.get(ismmilaf);
Files.write(p, moarif1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: `FileWriter` does not allow you to specify the output charset, it always uses the default charset of the underlying platform. If you want to specify an explicit charset, you have to "*construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream*" instead, like the `FileWriter` documentation says to.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it as the third param of PrintStream like this:

```
foostream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
stream  = new PrintStream(foostream, true, "UTF_8");
stream.println("whatever");
```

or using StandardCharsets.DesiredEncoding (i didn't remember it well but maybe you need to use .toString() on it, like:

```
stream  = new PrintStream(foostream, true, StandardCharsets.UTF-8.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using different `charset` and those characters do not belong to that, could you try using `UTF-8`, e.g.:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("G://data//123.txt");
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String stringa = "L’uomo più forte";
        w.write(stringa);
        w.write("\n");
        w.write("pause");
        w.write("\n");
        w.flush();
        w.close();
```