# corrupt pdf file while writing the bytes to stream

Tags: java, arrays, pdf

Facing a problem while implementing a java-ws service for downloading a pdf file from another webservice. Below is the piece of code for the same.decode() is used because of the webservice(this java code is invoking) is responding with encoded binary-base-64. I could see the PDF is downloaded in the given location but when i open with pdf reader, it says the file is corrupt.   Could you please help me ?

```
public DownloadFileResponse DownloadResponseMapper(Header header, DownloadDocumentResponseType response){
        DownloadFileResponse result = new DownloadFileResponse();
        result.setHeader(header);
        Status status = new Status();
        status.setStatusCode(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(response.getStatus().getStatusCode())));
        status.setStatusMessage(response.getStatus().getMessage());
        result.setStatus(status);
        if(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(response.getStatus().getStatusCode()))) != "0") {
            String qNameFile = FileExchange.getProperty("fileSystem.sharedLocation") + "/" + "result.pdf";
            try {
                byte[] fileContent = FileUtil.decode(response.getFile());
                System.out.println(response.getFile());
                FileUtil.writeByteArraysToFile(qNameFile, fileContent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                _logger.info(e.getStackTrace());
            }
            // calculate the hash of the file using two algorithm SHA-256/SHA-512
            List<FileHashType> hashes = FileUtil.calculateHash(result.getFile());
            result.setFileHash(hashes);
        }
        return result;
    }


public static void writeByteArraysToFile(String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.write(content);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }
```

Comment: What library if the FileUtil from? What about the object returned result.getFile()? what class is it?

Comment: Are you sure that the web server is providing the encoded file in a good format?
You should also check the charset when writing the file :https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322496/2768318

Comment: @Gaetano *"You should also check the charset when writing the file"* - the op wants to store a byte array, not a string. Thus, no charset is involved in writing it.

Comment: @Gaetano : FileUtil is my own class and it is not any library. The getFile returns b64 decoded file content. Hence, in my next step, i am decoding it. Also, as mkl says, i do not think charset is involved in writing this file. And, i am made sure that the sending is sending a valid content and it is not broken.

Comment: Could you send me the code of FileUtil also? and of DownloadFileResponse?

Comment: Hey Guys.. Thanks for the advice. I rechecked the packets that are coming from the webservice. It looks like it is broken. However, i would like to thank all for the guidelines.